# How to handle Login Authentication pop up without using Auto it?

Tags: java, selenium, authentication

How to handle Login Authentication pop up without using Auto it?

Can any one could help me in doing this...

Comment: is it windows based control or browser pop up?

Comment: window based Login Authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use like below:-

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

Give your username in place of username, same for password and change example.com with your website

OR

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(**username**, **password**));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: The code is working only in my system.I tried in another system it is not working. Do you know why?

Comment: Try to provide more wait time and try to put thread.sleep(); also

Answer (score 0):

[Joe Colantonio](http://www.joecolantonio.com/) has explained - How to Automate Non-Browser Based Functionality in very simple steps.  Please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988733/how-to-handle-login-authentication-pop-up-without-using-auto-it). Please note that he has used AutoIT for the same [which is your requirement], but it will work only for windows platfrom

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to handle basic authentication popup which comes through Java Script. You can handle the java script based authentication by putting the UserId and Password in your URL. Make your URL something like below and them It wont ask to enter the credentials in popup

`http://UserID:Password@YourWebsite.com`